# "Seen By" feature in Facebook groups

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to implement a post seen by feature like in FB groups using JS and PHP , I managed to get the seen counts from the  scrolling actions but I need to know whether the user just scrolled it down or actually spending time to read it ( some kind of a scroll speed tracker or something similar)

```
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      var $divs = $('.singlePost');

      var top = $.grep($divs, function(item) {

          return $(item).position().top <= winTop;
      });

      if (top.length > 0) {
          var len = top.length;
          var viewingPost = top[len-1]
          if( ! $(viewingPost).hasClass("seen")){

              var seenData = {"name":"postId", "value":$(viewingPost).attr('data-sharedId')}
              parseSeenData( seenData ,viewingPost );
           }
      }
```

above is the code which I did to get the seen count,need to get some info regarding user spent enough time on each post to read it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some sort of timer that times how long each post is "seen" before you actually set it as seen.

Maybe [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) will help?

I'm thinking you could use something like `setTimeout()`, and add a view duration property to each post. Use `setTimeout` to increase the view duration on whatever post is being looked at by one second, every second, and then, after it reaches the value you want, set that post as "seen". Hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: yeah I'm using timeouts but kind of a different way than u mentioned, anyway you know how FB does this ? I just want to get an idea ,

Comment: @LakshithaUdara I'm not familiar with how facebook does it, sorry. But if what you're doing works, then it works, right?

Comment: yep what I'm doing currently is that getting the viewing posts and then check the scrolling speeds if user is scrolling faster than to a threshold speed then the posts won't be count as seen.